# Disabling SSO users in Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, active-directory, single-sign-on

I am setting up Azure AD with Jenkins to onboard users

I have this setup and working but trying to understand how to handle when employee are terminated.

I want to ensure they no longer have access to jenkins, however after testing this scenario, they no longer have access to login but if they are already signed in, they still have access.

Is there a way to prevent access if they are already signed in?

Comment: Try to revoke user refresh token as it is present till expiry by using  `Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId "$ObjectId"`. This may clear browser session of user.

Answer (score 0):

As token has some expiry and generates refresh token time to time till the expiry. Try by using the powershell command to revoke the user refresh token .

```
1.  Connect-AzureAD

2.  $ObjectId=(Get-AzureADUser -All 1| where {$_.UserPrincipalName -like "XXX@XXXX.OnMicrosoft.com"}).ObjectId

3.  Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId "$ObjectId"
```

(If you do not know upn, you can directly copy object id from user profile)

Or you can use `Revoke-AzureADSignedInUserAllRefreshToken` after first command.

> Note : This may clear current browser active sessions and may not be
> all  and takes couple mins to come to action.

**References:**

1. [Forcefully revoke azure ad user session |
   scomandothergeekystuff.com](https://scomandothergeekystuff.com/2019/08/27/forcefully-revoke-azure-ad-user-session-access-immediately/)
   ( or )

   [kill all active user sessions in any azure ad office 365 application
   | exchangekb.com](https://exchangekb.com/2020/03/28/kill-all-active-user-sessions-in-any-azure-ad-office-365-application/)
2. [msal-net-clear-token-cache | MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-clear-token-cache)